# Android iText com.itextpdf.text.Image getInstance tooks very very long

Tags: android, image, performance, itext

i am creating a Android app. With it, i create a PDF File with itext for Android.

Everything is working, but for some reason adding a Image to a table cell with  Image.getInstance(path) is extremly slow.

My code:

```
public static PdfPCell createImageCell(String path) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfPCell cell=null;
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "0");
        Image img = Image.getInstance(path);
        Log.i(TAG, "1");
        cell = new PdfPCell(img, true);
        Log.i(TAG, "2");
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
        Log.i(TAG, "3");
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        Log.i(TAG, "4");
        cell.setFixedHeight(3f);
        Log.i(TAG, "5");
        return cell;
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logo not found!", e1);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And the log output:

```
09-01 14:26:25.891 10039-10039/package I/KundendatenActivity: 0
09-01 14:26:47.721 10039-10039/package I/KundendatenActivity: 1
09-01 14:26:47.721 10039-10039/package I/KundendatenActivity: 2
09-01 14:26:47.721 10039-10039/package I/KundendatenActivity: 3
09-01 14:26:47.721 10039-10039/package I/KundendatenActivity: 4
09-01 14:26:47.721 10039-10039/package I/KundendatenActivity: 5
```

As you can see, between the output 0 and 1 , there are 22 seconds.

Any idea why? Can i speed it up?

Edit:
It seams depending on the image. Other images are much faster.
As test image for this case i Used:
https://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fde%2Fthumb%2F6%2F63%2FT%25C3%259CV_S%25C3%25BCd_logo.svg%2F2000px-T%25C3%259CV_S%25C3%25BCd_logo.svg.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDatei%3AT%25C3%259CV_S%25C3%25BCd_logo.svg&docid=RGxhM1QU0Lag_M&tbnid=x5GThV255RHtvM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwikl4eKgoTWAhWIPBQKHdJtDgMQMwhIKAAwAA..i&w=2000&h=2000&client=ubuntu&bih=1318&biw=2560&q=t%C3%BCv%20s%C3%BCd&ved=0ahUKEwikl4eKgoTWAhWIPBQKHdJtDgMQMwhIKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8

However with this picture it takes 22 seconds.

Comment: Which version of iTextG are you using?

Comment: I am using 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'

Comment: From the description, this sounds like IO slowdown to me, since loading an image using a path will call the relevant IO methods to read the image into memory.

Comment: possible, i downloaded the image and saved it on the internal storage. (Like i did with the others(faster loaded) pictures, too). I suggest a problem with the opacity. Maybe thats why this picture is so slow